# Tree Node Checked behavior on a TreeView in Compact Framework 3.5 running on Windows Mobile 6.5

Tags: compact-framework, treeview, windows-mobile-6, checked

I have been upgrading an existing .NET Windows Mobile application to use the 3.5 version of the compact framework and to run on Windows Mobile 6.5. I have a form with a TreeView. The TreeView.Checkboxes property is set to true so that each node has a check box. This gives no trouble in all previous versions of Windows Mobile.

However, in version 6.5 when you click on a check box it appears to check and then uncheck instantaneously. But it only raises the AfterCheck event once. The only way I can get a check to stick is by double clicking it (which is the wrong behavior).

Has anyone seen this behavior? Does anyone know of a workaround for it?

I have included a simple test form. Dump this form into a Visual Studio 2008 Smart Device application targeted at Windows Mobile 6 to see what I mean.

```
Public Class frmTree
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

#Region " Windows Form Designer generated code "
Public Sub New()
    MyBase.new()
    ' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

End Sub

'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
    If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
        components.Dispose()
    End If
    MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
End Sub

'Required by the Windows Form Designer
Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer
Friend WithEvents TreeView1 As System.Windows.Forms.TreeView
Private mainMenu1 As System.Windows.Forms.MainMenu

'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
'Do not modify it using the code editor.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Dim TreeNode1 As System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode = New System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode("Node0")
    Dim TreeNode2 As System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode = New System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode("Node2")
    Dim TreeNode3 As System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode = New System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode("Node3")
    Dim TreeNode4 As System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode = New System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode("Node4")
    Dim TreeNode5 As System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode = New System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode("Node1")
    Dim TreeNode6 As System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode = New System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode("Node5")
    Dim TreeNode7 As System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode = New System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode("Node6")
    Dim TreeNode8 As System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode = New System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode("Node7")
    Me.mainMenu1 = New System.Windows.Forms.MainMenu
    Me.TreeView1 = New System.Windows.Forms.TreeView
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    '
    'TreeView1
    '
    Me.TreeView1.CheckBoxes = True
    Me.TreeView1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(37, 41)
    Me.TreeView1.Name = "TreeView1"
    TreeNode2.Text = "Node2"
    TreeNode3.Text = "Node3"
    TreeNode4.Text = "Node4"
    TreeNode1.Nodes.AddRange(New System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode() {TreeNode2, TreeNode3, TreeNode4})
    TreeNode1.Text = "Node0"
    TreeNode6.Text = "Node5"
    TreeNode7.Text = "Node6"
    TreeNode8.Text = "Node7"
    TreeNode5.Nodes.AddRange(New System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode() {TreeNode6, TreeNode7, TreeNode8})
    TreeNode5.Text = "Node1"
    Me.TreeView1.Nodes.AddRange(New System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode() {TreeNode1, TreeNode5})
    Me.TreeView1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(171, 179)
    Me.TreeView1.TabIndex = 0
    '
    'frmTree
    '
    Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(96.0!, 96.0!)
    Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Dpi
    Me.AutoScroll = True
    Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(240, 268)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.TreeView1)
    Me.Menu = Me.mainMenu1
    Me.Name = "frmTree"
    Me.Text = "frmTree"
    Me.ResumeLayout(False)

End Sub
#End Region

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to create a workaround for this, but had to go to extreme measures to do so. It appears that the behavior we are seeing occurs because the Click event is being fired both from the MouseDown and the MouseUp events (instead of just the mouse up as it would in Windows or previous versions).

To show this, you can start by tapping on the checkbox, leaving your finger on the screen and dragging off the check box. It will become checked from the MouseDown event and will stay checked because the MouseUp event is not fired when you lift your finger from a different position. The same works for tapping off the checkbox and dragging on.

In order to prevent the double click behavior you must suppress one of the MouseDown or MouseUp events. I ended up creating a control that inherited the TreeView and used WndProcHooker to hook the OnMouseDown method and mark it as handled so that the MouseDown Event never actually gets fired. I figured that made the most sense (you must have your finger over the checkbox when you lift it).

Here is a link to the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229658.aspx) about the WndProcHooker. Below is my code for my TreeViewInherit class. While this works, I am still astonished that these are the lengths I have to go to to get this working. Additionally, I am not looking forward to the day MS fixes this and thus breaks my workaround in the process.

```
    Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms

Public Class TreeViewInherit
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.TreeView

#Region " Variables "
    Private mBlnHandleMouseDown As Boolean
#End Region

#Region " Methods "

    Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()

    'Set the Handle Mouse Down based on the OS. if 6.5 and up, then handle it.
    mBlnHandleMouseDown = (System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 5 AndAlso System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor >= 2 AndAlso System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Build >= 21234)
    If mBlnHandleMouseDown Then
        WndProcHooker.HookWndProc(Me, New WndProcHooker.WndProcCallback(AddressOf Me.WM_LButtonDown_Handler), Win32.WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
    End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseDown(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    'Don't Call the Base to prevent the extra event from firing
    If Not mBlnHandleMouseDown Then
        MyBase.OnMouseDown(e)
    End If
    End Sub

#End Region

#Region " Events "
    Private Function WM_LButtonDown_Handler(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer, ByRef handled As Boolean) As Integer
    Try
        Me.Capture = False

        Dim lastCursorCoordinates As Win32.POINT = Win32.LParamToPoint(lParam)
        If Me.ClientRectangle.Contains(lastCursorCoordinates.X, lastCursorCoordinates.Y) Then
        OnMouseDown(New MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Left, 1, lastCursorCoordinates.X, lastCursorCoordinates.Y, 0))
        End If
        handled = True
        Return 0
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    End Try
    End Function
#End Region

End Class
```

Good Luck!

Comment: The linked to WndProcHooker in the MSDN documentation does not compile for the CompactFramework 3.5, which is what the question was asking about.

Comment: "type or namespace 'Win32' cannot be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)". Hmm... I wish I knew if I was missing a using or assembly reference, unfortunately that code on MSDN does not show which using directives are being used, and it does not have a downloadable solution that would show which assembly references are being used. Plus I think it is for the full .NET Framework, so that is probably why it is not working.

Comment: The `Win32` class here got it to compile for me: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/netcfteam/archive/2005/05/20/420551.aspx

Comment: While that Win32 class did get the `WndProcHooker` code to compile (from the MSDN link), the code in this answer still does not. `Win32.POINT` and `Win32.LParamToPoint(lParam)` do not exist. Where is this `Win32` class you are using?

Comment: I found the second part of that article. Toward the end it randomly spews portions of the class missing from the first article. The code is not even shown inside a class, you have to read the article to see it is part of that Win32 class. This gets more of it compiling...: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/netcfteam/archive/2005/05/23/421143.aspx

Comment: Even with part 2 of the Win32 class, at least one thing is still not compiling. Actually it is from part 2 of the Win32 class. Inside the structure definition for `TVHITTESTINFO` it references a `POINT` type in all capital letters even though this `POINT` type does not actually exist anywhere...

Comment: Since only x and y were being used from POINT, I just defined a POINT struct with an int x and an int y. The code I have is at least compiling now, hopefully it will work. I still have yet to pull in all the code from the answer, so I would not be surprised if I run into more compilation problems. I found a reference to a POINT structure inside Windows defined this way, so hopefully I am on the right track, although this is not documentation for Mobile or CE: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162805(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: One more thing I had to add to the Win32 class to get this all to compile: `public const uint WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;`

Comment: Once you get this all to compile, this solution does cause the checkboxes to visually display properly. I also confirmed the Checked property is also set properly. However, the `AfterCheck` event of the `TreeView` no longer gets called. Also, if you try to override the `OnAfterCheck` method, this never gets called either.

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to use this alternative: http://blogs.southworks.net/mconverti/2009/06/22/optional-checkable-tree-view-control-for-net-compact-framework-35/

Answer (score 1):

To get over the problem of the AfterCheck event not firing I found that I could get the node clicked on and then use that to call AfterCheck, that works but I then found AfterCheck was called before the state of the checkbox had been changed so instead raised my own event and handled it appropriately.

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms

Public Class TreeViewInherit
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.TreeView

    'Occurs when the user clicks a TreeNode with the mouse.
    Public Event MouseDownOveride(ByVal node As TreeNode)

#Region " Variables "
    Private mBlnHandleMouseDown As Boolean
#End Region

#Region " Methods "



    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()

        'Set the Handle Mouse Down based on the OS. if 6.5 and up, then handle it.
        mBlnHandleMouseDown = (System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 5 AndAlso System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor >= 2 AndAlso System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Build >= 21234)
        If mBlnHandleMouseDown Then
            WndProcHooker.HookWndProc(Me, New WndProcHooker.WndProcCallback(AddressOf Me.WM_LButtonDown_Handler), Win32.WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseDown(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
        'Don't Call the Base to prevent the extra event from firing
        If Not mBlnHandleMouseDown Then
            MyBase.OnMouseDown(e)
        End If
    End Sub


    Private Function FindTreeNodeFromHandle(ByVal tnc As TreeNodeCollection, ByVal handle As IntPtr) As TreeNode
        For Each tn As TreeNode In tnc
            If tn.Handle = handle Then
                Return tn
            End If
            ' we couldn't have clicked on a child of this node if this node
            ' is not expanded!
            If tn.IsExpanded Then
                Dim tn2 As TreeNode = FindTreeNodeFromHandle(tn.Nodes, handle)
                If tn2 IsNot Nothing Then
                    Return tn2
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Return Nothing
    End Function


#End Region

#Region " Events "
    Private Function WM_LButtonDown_Handler(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As UInteger, ByVal wParam As UInteger, ByVal lParam As Integer, ByRef handled As Boolean) As Integer
        Try
            Me.Capture = False

            Dim lastCursorCoordinates As Win32.POINT = Win32.LParamToWin32POINT(lParam)

            If Me.ClientRectangle.Contains(lastCursorCoordinates.X, lastCursorCoordinates.Y) Then
                OnMouseDown(New MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Left, 1, lastCursorCoordinates.X, lastCursorCoordinates.Y, 0))
            End If
            handled = True


            Dim msgPos As Point = Win32.LParamToPoint(CInt(Win32.GetMessagePos()))
            msgPos = Me.PointToClient(msgPos)

            ' check to see if the click was on an item
            Dim hti As New Win32.TVHITTESTINFO()
            hti.pt.X = msgPos.X
            hti.pt.Y = msgPos.Y
            Dim hitem As Integer = Win32.SendMessage(Me.Handle, Win32.TVM_HITTEST, 0, hti)
            Dim htMask As UInteger = (Win32.TVHT_ONITEMICON Or Win32.TVHT_ONITEMLABEL Or Win32.TVHT_ONITEMINDENT Or Win32.TVHT_ONITEMBUTTON Or Win32.TVHT_ONITEMRIGHT Or Win32.TVHT_ONITEMSTATEICON)

            If hti.flags = Win32.TVHT_ONITEMSTATEICON Then
                RaiseEvent MouseDownOveride(FindTreeNodeFromHandle(Me.Nodes, hti.hItem))
            End If


            Return 0
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        End Try
    End Function
#End Region

End Class
```

Works ok.

We asked MS for an answer and they gave us a workaround which involves capturing the click and checking or un-checking the checkbox as desired.  Have not tired it yet but if it does the job I will post that as well.

Comment: Where is `WndProcHooker` coming from?